# What paper cups does can be used for both cold drinks and coffee?

Tags: cup, coffee-shop

I see a coffee shop named Blue Bottle use their paper cups for hot and cold drinks. I wonder what paper-cup tech this is?

In my shop experience, using hot cups for cold drinks make them soggy. I'd like to get onboard with their manufacturer, because I don't want to have to keep two kinds of cups!

I wonder if anyone knows. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @wearashirt, welcome to Coffee SE, please feel free to take the [tour](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Hot cups get soggy?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that company, but I assume [insulated paper cup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrShmBVvntQ) is what you are looking for.

You may have a quick Internet search for brands and whole sellers.